# Result of getValue in for-each loop for TreeMap<String, Set<String>>

Tags: java, foreach, set, treemap, getvalue

(Just setting up).

```
TreeMap< String, Set< String>> map;
```

the strings are names and the Set are different timestamps, so every timestamp can have several names, if all have chosen the same time

...

(initiating)

```
map = new TreeMap< String, Set< String>>;
```

...

```
for (Map.entry< String, Set< String>> mapEx : map.entrySet()){
```

what would map.getValue result in here?
like, would the following code result in me being able to look at each string in the Set part from map and print them?

```
for(String stringEx : map.getValue()){

  System.Out.Println(stringEx);

}
```

Comment: Instead of using an actual iterator, I was wondering if it is possible to simplify it to a for-each loop (to me they are simpler)

Comment: What is the final goal ?

Comment: me being able to look at each string in the Set part from map and print them (theoretically)

Comment: ok, I'have a more complete answer, with easier ways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map.getValue will be `Set<String>` indeed.

If you have this loop

```
for(String stringEx : mapEx.getValue()){

  System.out.println(stringEx);

}
```

inside this loop

```
     for (Map.entry< String, Set< String>> mapEx : map.entrySet()){ 
        // For each map entry value is set 
//of strings which can be printed by the loop shown before
     }
```

Combined loops

```
for (Map.entry< String, Set< String>> mapEx : map.entrySet()){ 

       for(String stringEx : mapEx.getValue()){

      System.out.println(stringEx);

    }

         }
```

Comment: Nice, just what I wished. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose 3 different ways to achieve that :

*Using Java 8 Stream* : iterate over values, then over `String` from each `Set`

```
map.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
//  over Set        //over String from each Set       
// System.out::println === s -> System.out.println(s) and can be whatever you want
```

---

*Classic for each* on the differents `Sets` :

```
for (Set<String> set : map.values()) {
    for (String stringEx : set) {
        System.out.println(stringEx);
    }
}
```

---

*For each* on the differents `entries`, and then take their values (`Set<String>`):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (String val : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```